# How to recover a commit in git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I worked on something all day in a personal project, and committed it to a branch. I then realized I was going to commit to master and created a new branch to push to, and git switched to that branch. Afterwards I switched back but couldn't find my commit. Is there any way to recover the commit from before I created the branch? It reverted a lot of my work.

Comment: Which are the commands you executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git reflog` should help, as long as it was committed at some point it will still be there.

You'll get output like the following:

```
57a5b3a (HEAD -> some-branch, origin/some-branch) HEAD@{0}: commit: made changes
3092bca HEAD@{1}: commit: Other changes
7021685 HEAD@{2}: commit: More changes
2d882b8 HEAD@{3}: commit: even more changes
dc30cbc (origin/master, master) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to some-branch
dc30cbc (origin/master, master) HEAD@{5}: commit: I hope your commit messages are better than this
```

Just find the one that looks like the one you want and check it out

Comment: I think I found it, if I checkout the commit, should the changes be there locally?

Comment: they will be there locally once you check it out, if I remember right you'll be in "detached head state", so once you see your changes you'll probably have to do "git checkout -b some_branch" and then commit it there

Comment: Do you know how to merge the detached head to a branch? Do you just push to one of the remote branches?

Comment: there is probably a better way, but I would do: `git checkout -b temp` `git add .` `git commit -m whatever` `git checkout real-branch` `git merge temp` `git push`

Answer (score 1):

The [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) command may be useful here. It will show the history of where the branch tip has been.

I'm not sure how you might have "lost" a commit if you truly did commit the work and are now checked out on that branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the message (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> might help), you cand find the commit with:

```
git log --all --grep 'the message'
```